# EF 5 removing quotes on query

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, database-performance

I'm having a problem with EF5 regarding a string field on database (Oracle) that contains only numbers.

Here's the sample code:

```
using (Entities ex = new Entities())
{
string nrcart = "861858662";
GLB_PESSOA_OPERADORA pessoa = ex.GLB_PESSOA_OPERADORA.FirstOrDefault(p => p.NR_CARTEIRINHA == nrcart);
}
```

My problem is that EF is building the following query to the database:

```
SELECT "Extent1"."ID_PESSOA_OPERADORA"      AS "ID_PESSOA_OPERADORA",
       "Extent1"."NR_CARTEIRINHA"           AS "NR_CARTEIRINHA"
FROM   "GLB_PESSOA_OPERADORA" "Extent1"
WHERE  ("Extent1"."NR_CARTEIRINHA" = 861858662 /* @p__linq__0 */)
  AND (ROWNUM <= (1))
```

Note that the query doesn't surround the parameter with '' on where statement.
The field in the database, the attribute in the returning class, the mapping on the Model and the nrcart variable are ALL string typed. Why is it removing the quotes?

Without them, the database is not able to use the index and the query is runnig too slow.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you tried `string nrcart = "\"861858662\"";` or `string nrcart = "'861858662'";`?

Comment: Yes. I just tried it now. Thanks for the reply. But the results weren't better.

With nrcart = "\"861858662\"", the result sql was WHERE ("Extent1"."NR_CARTEIRINHA" = '"861858662"')

With nrcart = "'861858662'", was ("Extent1"."NR_CARTEIRINHA" = '''861858662'''

Both wrong, also I want to know why it isn't adding the quotes, considering that the field and the entity are both strings. Why it decided to not include them just because the string has no letters?

Comment: If I try with nrcart = "abc123", it works just fine. So, if I let the user enter the string for query, I'll have to check if the string has or not any letter and do the proper adding of quotes?

There must be a better way to force EF to use the quotes when querying a string field, doesn't matter if the string has or not a letter.